# SQL server matching two table on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have two tables one storing user skills another storing skills required for a job. I want to match how many skills a of each user matches with a job.
The table structure is

```
Table1: User_Skills
| ID | User_ID | Skill    |
---------------------------
| 1  |  1      |  .Net    |
---------------------------
| 2  |  1      |  Software|
---------------------------
| 3  |  1      |  Engineer|
---------------------------
| 4  |  2      |  .Net    |
---------------------------
| 5  |  2      |  Software|
---------------------------

Table2: Job_Skills_Requirement
| ID | Job_ID | Skill     |
--------------------------
| 1  |  1      |  .Net    |
---------------------------
| 2  |  1      |  Engineer|
---------------------------
| 3  |  1      |  HTML    |
---------------------------
| 4  |  2      |  Software|
---------------------------
| 5  |  2      |  HTML    |
---------------------------
```

I was trying to have comma separated skills and compare but these can be in different order.

**Edit**
All the answers here are excellent. The result I am looking for is matching all jobs with all users as later on I will match other properties as well.

Comment: Please remember to show what you've already tried.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match *all* users and *all* jobs, then Mureinik's otherwise excellent answer is not correct.

You need to generate all the rows first, which I would do using a `cross join` and then count the matching ones:

```
select u.user_id, j.job_id, count(jsr.job_id) as skills_in_common
from users u cross join
     jobs j left join
     user_skills us
     on us.user_id = u.user_id left join
     Job_Skills_Requirement jsr
     on jsr.job_id = j.job_id and
        jsr.skill = us.skill
group by u.user_id, j.job_id;
```

Note:  This assumes the existence of a `users` and a `jobs` table.  You can of course generate these using subqueries.

Answer (score 6):

You could join the tables by the `skill` columns and count the matches:

```
SELECT   user_id, job_id, COUNT(*) AS matching_skills
FROM     user_skills u
JOIN     job_skills_requirement j ON u.skill = j.skill
GROUP BY user_id, job_id
```

EDIT:
IF you want to also show users and jobs that have no matching skills, you can use a `full outer join` instead.

```
SELECT          user_id, job_id, COUNT(*) AS matching_skills
FROM            user_skills u
FULL OUTER JOIN job_skills_requirement j ON u.skill = j.skill
GROUP BY        user_id, job_id
```

EDIT 2:
As Jiri Tousek commented, the above query will produce `null`s where there's no match between a user and a job. If you want a full Cartesian products between them, you could use (abuse?) the `cross join` syntax and count how many skills actually match between each user and each job:

```
SELECT     user_id, 
           job_id,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN u.skill = j.skill THEN 1 END) AS matching_skills
FROM       user_skills u
CROSS JOIN job_skills_requirement j
GROUP BY   user_id, job_id
```

Comment: How would this work for combinations that have no skills in common?

Comment: @JiriTousek It would exclude them because of the `JOIN`. If you wanted to include non-matches, you would need to make it a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` includes rows from the table on the left side of the join that do not match any rows on the table on the right side of the join. For rows with no matches, the columns from the table on the right will be null.

Comment: @JiriTousek with the current query, users and jobs that have no matches will be omitted. If you want to show them too, you could use a full outer join instead of an inner join - see my edited answer for details.

Comment: I thought full outer join would produce rows like `null, SQL developer, 1` and `John, null, 1` instead of `John, SQL Developer, 0`. Test on Oracle seems to support this. Not sure OP needs any of that, I was just wondering how it could be done to be correct for total mismatch as well.

Comment: @JiriTousek that's a good point, thanks! Using (abusing?) a `cross join` seems to do the trick (see my edited answer for details).

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH User_Skills(ID,User_ID,Skill)AS(
   SELECT 1,1,'.Net' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,1,'Software' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,1,'Engineer' UNION ALL
   SELECT 4,2,'.Net' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5,2 ,'Software'
),Job_Skills_Requirement(ID,Job_ID,Skill)AS(
   SELECT 1,1,'.Net' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,1,'Engineer' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,1,'HTML' UNION ALL
   SELECT 4,2,'Software' UNION ALL
   SELECT 5,2 ,'HTML'
),Job_User_Skill AS (
   SELECT j.Job_ID,u.User_ID,u.Skill
   FROM Job_Skills_Requirement AS j INNER JOIN User_Skills AS u ON u.Skill=j.Skill
)
SELECT jus.Job_ID,jus.User_ID,COUNT(jus.Skill),STUFF(c.Skills,1,1,'') AS Skill
FROM Job_User_Skill AS jus
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ','+j.Skill FROM Job_User_Skill AS j WHERE j.Job_ID=jus.Job_ID AND j.User_ID=jus.User_ID FOR XML PATH('')) c(Skills)
GROUP BY jus.Job_ID,jus.User_ID,c.Skills
ORDER BY jus.Job_ID
```

```
Job_ID      User_ID                 Skill
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
1           1           2           .Net,Engineer
1           2           1           .Net
2           1           1           Software
2           2           1           Software
```